# Calculate derivative with group by some time interval

Tags: r

I have data with `time` and `rps`. Time range is 10 min, and rps is growing linearly from 0 to 10.
**How to calculate derivative by some time period** (let it be 1 min)?
Unfortunately, I didn't find properly function... Thanks in advance!

In my example the answer is: +1 rps each 1 min

```
time,rps
2023-10-11 16:40:20,0.400
2023-10-11 16:40:25,0
2023-10-11 16:40:30,0.200
2023-10-11 16:40:35,0.400
2023-10-11 16:40:40,0.200
...
2023-10-11 16:50:05,9.80
2023-10-11 16:50:10,9.80
2023-10-11 16:50:15,10
```

---

**Edit**: According to the advice, I add a simpler example with the same expected deviation `1`:

```
time,rps
2023-10-11 16:40:00,1
2023-10-11 16:41:00,2
2023-10-11 16:42:00,3
2023-10-11 16:43:00,4
2023-10-11 16:44:00,5
```

[image]

Comment: Create a linear interpolation and then use  it to get a value for items in a sequence spaced to your chosen range and interval. To get a coded answer edit your example to remove the “…”. I for one deprecate the use of ellipses when offering examples. The message to a potential repost dent is that the questioner can’t be bothered to display a full example.

Comment: Sorry, but the full example is too long for publish. Moreover, my question is about how to in general compute the rate of change per unit of time between subsequent.
If you wish here you are: ```
time,rps
2023-10-11 16:40:00,1
2023-10-11 16:41:00,2
2023-10-11 16:42:00,3
2023-10-11 16:43:00,4
2023-10-11 16:44:00,5```

Comment: Offered below is an example one one of the proper ways of including a MCVE. The other more compact (and faster for you and me) method would have been to post the output from `dput(head(your_data.frame_name))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the offered example gives a fairly trivial example where the interval is already at desired interval and the "derivative" which is really the delta per 1 minute, I'll offer a result that yields the per second difference.

```
dat <- read.csv(text='time,rps
                2023-10-11 16:40:00,1
                2023-10-11 16:41:00,2
                2023-10-11 16:42:00,3
                2023-10-11 16:43:00,4
                2023-10-11 16:44:00,5', colClasses=c("POSIXct",'numeric'))
#Make use your "datetimes" were not read into the R object as factors or text"
afun <- approxfun(x=dat$time, y=dat$rps)
diffvals <- diff( afun(seq(dat[1,1], dat[4,1], by="1 secs")) )
diffvals
#----------
  [1] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
  [9] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [17] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [25] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [33] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [41] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [49] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [57] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [65] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [73] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [81] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [89] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
 [97] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[105] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[113] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[121] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[129] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[137] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[145] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[153] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[161] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[169] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
[177] 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667
```

Comment: Hm, it's a good solution! Now I see, you're using interpolation and separated by interval time values. 
Thanks you for your answer, and also appreciate your patience with my question!

Comment: I should ask:
How much results are precise? Is there any difference between use interpolation instead of compute derivative?

Comment: Not sure what the concern is about precision. A derivative is a function that takes a continuous function as input. Computers can do symbolic differentiation if you offer a continuous function, but if they are offered only a vector of discrete values as given here, then either linear differences or some sort of spline  smoothing are the choices.

Comment: There are numerous Q or A's that a brought up by the search `[r] spline interpolation`

Comment: I’ll add a note about `D` and `deriv` which are a bit higher level approaches and maybe add something about how to access symbolic differentiation.